# The Bible says there is one God who is eternal. Does Joseph Smith, LDS founder, prophet, seer and revelator contradict the Bible?

Tags: lds, biblical-theology

He said, "In the beginning, the head of the Gods called a council of the Gods: and they came together and concocted a plan to create the world and people in it." Joseph Smith Jr., Journal of Discourses, vol. 6, pg5.

He also said, "Sons of God who exalt themselves to be Gods, even from before the foundation of the world, and are the only Gods I have reverence for." (Joseph Smith, History of the Church, vol, 6, Pp. 473-479.

One more quote, "We have imagined and supposed that God was God from all eternity. I will now refute that idea, and take away the veil, so that you may see...he was once a man like us... (Smith, Teaching of the Prophet, pp. 345,346.)

How do the Mormons reconcile these statements from what the Bible teaches? Mark 12:32, "And the scribe said to Him/Jesus Christ, "Right, Teacher, You have truly stated that He/the Lord God is ONE: And there is no one else besides Him." Or Psalm 90:2, "Before the mountains were born, Or Thou didst give birth to the earth and the world, Even from everlasting to everlasting, Thou are God."

Comment: I have taken the liberty of slightly modifying the title to make it less confrontational. I hope you don't mind.  If you do, then please change it back again.

Comment: @Lesley Your fine, I have no objections. Thank You!

Comment: Although it may seem obvious to some, I think your header - especially - needs to clarify which 'bible' you mean. The Book of Mormon ? Joseph Smith's own "revision" (and additive alteration) of Genesis to Revelation [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith) ? or the Bible as it is commonly referred to, being a recognised translation of the recognised canonical text ?

Comment: @NigelJ THE "Bible" NigelJ. KJV etc. The Lds consider the Bom a Bible but many scholars do not. Lds say the Bom is ANOTHER testament of Jesus Christ. Jude 3 states, "earnestly contend for the faith which was ONCE delivered to the saints. There are a multitude of contradictions in the Bom. http://mit.irr.org/contradictions-between-book-of-mormon-and-bible My quotes of Smith are from their own multiple sources. Bom, Journal of Discourses, Book of Abraham, History of the church, the Pearl of great Price and others. Not one shred of evidence exists for the Bom and the civilizations it mentions.

Comment: @curiousdannii I chose to change the question to God being eternal as opposed to the subject of men being gods.

Comment: Seeing as you asked it again, I rolled this back.